# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one AsyncConfigurer may exist

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to get two ThreadPoolTaskExecutor by implementing AsyncConfigurer.

When I starting my application getting this exception:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one AsyncConfigurer may exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one AsyncConfigurer may exist
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AbstractAsyncConfiguration.setConfigurers(AbstractAsyncConfiguration.java:68) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

```
@EnableAsync
@Import({ Thread1.class, Thread2.class})
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
class Thread1 implements AsyncConfigurer{

    @Override
    @Bean(name="executor1")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
@Configuration
class Thread2 implements AsyncConfigurer{

    @Override
    @Bean(name="executor2")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService empService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/list/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Employee> getEmpDetails() throws Exception {
        return empService.getALlEmpl();
    }

}
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    @Async("executor1")
    public List<Employee> getEmpDetails(){
    }

    @Async("executor2")
    public Employee getCompanyDetail(String id){
    }

}
```

Can somebody take a look at it ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: What isn't clear about the exception? You clearly have 2 beans implementing `AsyncConfigurer` where only 1 is allowed.

Comment: I want to create two ThreadPoolexecutor in an application. And on basis of name qualifier I want to start method in async mode. So I tried this. Can you tell me how to achieve multiple ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in a single application.

Comment: To have multiple task executors you don't need multiple `AsyncConfigurer`s. Just define them as beans.

Comment: Thank you Deinum!!!

Comment: @M.Deinum cam you please elaborate here?

Comment: You can do what @M.Deinum said, but in my understanding you will not be able to define 2 different AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler, one for each executor.